# Hanning Window Bandwidth

Tags: signal-analysis, python, window-functions

I am using scipy's "scipy.signal.hanning" to determine a hanning window. This method returns an array with the window and specific number of points based on your input.

More info: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hanning.html

My question:

Is there a connection between the desirable window points output and the bandwidth of the Window?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you increase the window size the width of the main lobe decreases which results in more spectral resolution. So with a larger window size you could better differentiate two adjacent frequencies than with a smaller size.

However there is always a trade off between main lobe width and side lobes attenuation. As the size of the window increases you would get more resolution in frequency at the cost of reduced dynamic range of the spectrum due to relative decrease in the ratio of main lobe to side lobe magnitudes.

Comment: i have a problem with implementing 2 filters(iir and fir) in python, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If by Bandwidth of the window, you mean width of the main-lobe (shown by red line below), it is determined by the number of points $M$ in the window. More point $M$ implies "thinner" main lobe, which means when you apply this window to a signal, you can resolve 2 frequencies clearly if they are placed close apart.

[image]

For 2 closely placed frequencies $x_1[n] = e^{j0.5\pi n}$ and $x_2[n] = e^{j0.51\pi n}$, here is a zoomed view of frequency plot generated with 500 point Hann window
[image]

Next is zoomed view of frequency plot generated with 1000 point Hann window

[image]

As you can see in second figure you can easily resolve 2 frequencies while in the first it is difficult unless you really zoom into it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1455106, called *On the Use of Windows for Harmonic Analysis with Discrete Fourier Transform*. It is a long paper but the table on page labeled 55, or the fifth page of the document, gives information on many variants of windows. For example, you can look up the 3-dB bandwidth for the Hann window with different values of $a$ (where it is $\text{cos}^a$ in the windowing equation).

The bandwidth value will be given in units of DFT bins, but you can convert to radians: $x \text{ bins} \times \frac{2\pi /N \text{ radians}}{\text{bin}}=\frac{2\pi x}{N}$.

To follow off of jithin's answer, consider the two tones $x_1[n]=e^{j0.5\pi n}$ and $x_2[n]=e^{j0.51\pi n}$. Using the table the 3-dB bandwidth for the Hann window is $1.2$ bins, or $\frac{2 \pi \times 1.2}{128}=0.0589$, which is not fine enough to clearly pick up the two signals which differ only by $0.51\pi - 0.5\pi=0.0314$ radians. By changing the window to length 1024, the 3-dB bandwidth is $\frac{2 \pi \times 1.2}{1024}=0.0074$, which gives a fine enough resolution to clearly see the two tones in the spectrum.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even if you think you don't apply a window, an imaginary rectangular window is applied to your signal the moment you sample it and that is  because you get a finite set of samples (a chunk) from a signal with infinitely many samples in reality. It is like multiplying the samples you are getting by $1$ and the rest of the infinitely many samples by $0$, hence, it practically becomes multiplying your signal with a rectangular in time domain.

$N$ being the number of samples, for the rectangular window, the mainlobe width is $4\pi/N$ (thinking in digital frequencies, $\pi=Fs/2$), highest sidelobe is at $-13$dB and and the sidelobe drop-off rate is $-6$dB/octave in frequency domain.

So the mainlobe width is narrow but the highest sidelobe is not really that attenuated and drop-rate is not really great either!

Therefore, you need to intentionally design a better window than the rectangular one.

For any window we'd like to apply to our signal, we desire three things: narrow mainlobe width, high sidelobe attenuation and a high sidelobe drop-off rate all in frequency domain.

We want the narrow mainlobe width to have a better resolution. Say, for instance, you need to detect two closely spaced sinusoidals in frequency and your window is wider than the space between the two sinusoids, then those two sinusouids would smear after applying your window. You need the mainlobe as narrow as possible in that case.

However, there's always a mathematically inherent trade-off between the mainlobe width and the sidelobe attenuation of the window itself. We want also very attenuated sidelobes but lowering the sidelobes causes a widening of the mainlobe.

For the Hanning window, the mainlobe width is $8\pi/N$, highest sidelobe is at $-32$dB and and the sidelobe drop-off rate is $-18$dB/octave (except near ±$\pi$). So, you have a wider mainlobe width, which is worse than rectangular window!, but the highest sidelobe is attenuated a lot more and the drop-off rate for the following sidelobes is much better.

You might want to check out Hamming and Blackman windows for better SL attenuation, $-43$dB and $-57$dB respectively, if you are willing to sacrifice from the mainlobe width a bit more. Note that sidelobe drop-off rate for Hamming also becomes worse ($-6$dB, which is equivalent of rectangular) than Hanning.